# Grub: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, grubrescue

We have a Dell PowerEdge R730xd with 24 SSDs of 500GB each.
We need to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on this machine, and use it as a database (postgresql).

Our RAID controller is an Avago MEGARAID, and to my knowledge it behaved exactly like a H310 card.

I set up 2 Virtual Drives in RAID10 (16 and 8), so we have now

- `/dev/sda` (4TB)
- `/dev/sdb` (2TB)

I'm having troubles installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Even by choosing the most automatic installation (Guided: use entire disk `/dev/sda`) upon boot i get welcomed by the Grub rescue mode, with the message

```
attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
```

By executing some commands in grub rescue mode, I encountered these devices

- `(hd0,gpt3)`, unknown filesystem, should be the `swap` partition
- `(hd0,gpt2)`, recognized as `ext2` partition, contains `/boot` folder, but trying to access that returns the same error (*attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'*)
- `(hd0,gpt1)`,  recognized as *unknown filesystem*, it should be a `BIOSgrub` partition (we're in GPT mode after all)
- `(hd1)`, the 2TB drive

Trying to reinstall grub into `/dev/sda` using the Ubuntu LiveCD did not help. We're still welcomed by the same error. I could mount `/dev/sda2` in rescue mode and check the content of `grub.cfg`, but i'm not really sure what needs to be checked. Everywhere it was correctly referencing `(hd0,gpt2)`

Even after running boot-repair we get welcomed by the same error:

- Here is the `boot-info` of the system: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23726916/
- Here is the output of `boot-repair`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23726925/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by not having Ubuntu installed on a 2TB hard drive.

I repartitioned the 24 500GB drives as follows

- 2 RAID1 (500GB) - Ubuntu
- 16 RAID10 (4TB) - Main data storage
- 6 RAID10 (1.5TB) - Additional data storage

Installing Ubuntu on the 500GB RAID1 disks was no issue.

Answer (score 1):

> TL;DR: instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition
>   fix it

This is a common problem due to a security "feature" in many BIOS's which don't allow you to boot outside of the first 100GB (rougly) of your hard disk.  They've documented it with detailed instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingUbuntuOnBigDisk which worked to fix my issue.

My machine is a Dell PowerEdge T300 with a PERC H700 raid controller and 2 6TB RAID5 arrays running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.  I didn't want to loose all my data so instead of reformatting I re-partitioned the primary raid drive with a 1GB partition at the beginning of the disk (it took overnight to complete) and ran boot repair to relocate just the boot files to the new partition (full instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition )

My old solution (which I'm leaving here) only ***temporarily*** fixes it...

1. Physically disconnecting all drives not part of the virtual drive I was installing Ubuntu on
2. wiping the contents of the virtual drive ([re]initialized it in the raid controller GUI)
3. Completed the Ubuntu installation, shut down the machine, removed installation media
4. It booted into Ubuntu like normal and I was able to physically reconnect all drives without adverse effects :)

Hope this helps someone out there