# Ubuntu 20.04.3 on Dell R-620 with PERC H710 RAID controller installation reports error: attempt read-write outside of disk `hd0`

Tags: dell, raid

I am trying to optimize the reliability, HD usage efficiency, and HD performance of a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a Dell R-620 which has six 2 TB HD in a RAID-5 drive created and managed by the Dell PERC H710 PCIe RAID disk controller.

However after every clean installation from DVD and reboot, I get this error message from grub:

error: attempt read-write outside of disk `hd0`

I find that the Ubuntu installation program partitions the single /dev/sdb drive into what seems to me a reasonable set of three partitions:

/dev/sda1      1M    BIOS boot

/dev/sda2    512M    Microsoft basic data

/dev/sda3    9.1T    Linux filesystem

I can successfully install Ubuntu if I create one 2TB RAID-1 disk for '/' and a second RAID-5 disk for '/mnt/data', but in that configuration only 400 GB of the 4 TB of the two '/' disks is used and disk i/o for '/' is 80 MBps while the /mnt/data disk i/o is 400+ Mbps.

So before I surrender and use that less efficient disk configuration, can anyone suggest how I could get around this problem?

Comment: In case someone finds my question, I found the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/867047/grub-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0

In summary, you can't easily install Ubuntu 20.04 on a '/' partition larger than 2TB.  So if you have a large disk you need to manually partition it with a (e.g. 100 GByte) '/' partition when installing from the CDROM.

Answer (score 0):

I've been beating my head against simlar problems.  Turns out you need to be careful about uefi and bios boot alternatives with the 620.  In the F2 system configuration menu you can choose which boot type to use: the standard ubuntu flavours I've been playing with seem to dump their instal onto the machine as uefi.  Switching ht emachine to uefi boot just gives me a very rapid boot indeed.  Nice at least for me.  So far II've got some machines that seem to fly. Early days yet, but fingers crossed.  Hope it helps.